# Navigation Drawer, Activity, Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, activity, android-navigation-drawer

Всем привет, создаю приложение на Android с помощью Android Studio. Такой вопрос, у меня есть меню с пунктами:

---

1)Главная
2)Чаты
3)Категории(там будет архив всей полезной информации)
4)Настройки
и еще пару..

---

Как мне это реализовать: 1 активити и все остальные фрагменты; отдельный активити с drawer navigation, который будет наследоваться всеми фрагментами(чаты, категории и т.д.) и активити(главная, настройки и т.д.); все из активити? Или что-то другое?

Answer (score 0):

да можно и так, и так.  можно использовать и одну активити с кучей фрагментов, можно и построить все на активитях. А если интересует реализация чата, то готовый функционал предоставляется многими чат платформами, взять к примеру эту доку https://developers.connectycube.com/android/code-samples